# Does not work smbclient in Mac OS x 10.8.3. Socket is not connected

Tags: mac-osx, samba, mac, mac-osx-server, smbclient

last few days, i can't connect to any windows share in my domain from Mac OS x 10.8.3. 
According to reinstall, i can't do it, because there are a lot of settings in environment of this os.
Can you help me.

My command 
`mount -t smbfs //jenkins:MY_SECRET_PASSWORD@windows-server2012r2.example.local/builds/path/to/builds/ /Users/Mac/mnt/` 
After this i have: 
`mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected`

And if i will not fix it, do we have other ways to mount smb share (i mean maybe other binary of other smbclient, etc ...)

Comment: Can you use the -v (verbose) flag for more info? Anything showing up in cifs/smb logs?

Comment: @Smock sorry, but the same result without any additional debugging